# cannot configure log4net correctly

Tags: c#, log4net

I have tried to configure log4net via code but I am getting the following error when I use it as `Logger.Info("new bar");`:

> at NinjaTrader.Indicator.Logger.Info(Object msg) in c:\Users\Documents\NinjaTrader 7\bin\Custom\Indicator\STSVer1.cs:line 610
>   at NinjaTrader.Indicator.STSVer1.OnBarUpdate() in c:\Users\Documents\NinjaTrader 7\bin\Custom\Indicator\STSVer1.cs:line 108
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
public static class Logger
{
    private static log4net.ILog Log { get; set; }

    static Logger()
    { 
        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
        hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders(); /*Remove any other appenders*/

        FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender();
        fileAppender.AppendToFile = true;
        fileAppender.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
        fileAppender.File = @"c:\temp\logevents.txt";
        PatternLayout pl = new PatternLayout();
        pl.ConversionPattern = "%d [%2%t] %-5p [%-10c]   %m%n%n";
        pl.ActivateOptions();
        fileAppender.Layout = pl;
        fileAppender.ActivateOptions();

        log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(fileAppender);
        //Test logger
        ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


    //      Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Logger));
    }

    public static void Error(object msg)
    {
        Log.Error(msg);
    }

    public static void Error(object msg, Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(msg, ex);
    }

    public static void Error(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
    }

    public static void Info(object msg)
    {
        Log.Info(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Logger`-class static constructor, you don't initialize the property `Log`, but a new local variable called `Log`. Thus the property `Log` is `null`, when you call it from inside your `Info` method.

Remove the type name `ILog` from the following line of your code.

```
ILog Log =LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

BTW, the line just below, which you commented out, did the right thing - with respect to correctly initializing the property.